# Netbeans generated code wont change for Jframe

Tags: java, netbeans

I am making a very basic calculator for my first Jframe project in java. For my program to know what operation has been selected i plan on using booleans for add, divide, etc.

However, the default generated code has the classes as private, so I try to fix it by changing the generated code to public, it confirms that it was changed, and yet even after building the code remains as a private class. 
Any fix to this or better way to accomplish the same thing? I am relatively new to Java.

Comment: You can set/modify the access modifier in the properties editor (from memory), although I would consider leaving them `private` and have them chain call an appropriate `public`/`protected` method instead - but that's me

Comment: You might want to post some code to demonstrate what you're doing. Providing written descriptions which may (or may not) accurately describe what is actually going on is like trying to get an accurate medical diagnosis over the phone.